# How to select an operation on a sequence diagram message?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using EA Program Version: 15.1.1529 (Build 1529)

I have created a simple sequence diagram with two classes as vertical line on the diagram.
I create a message between the two classes without any issues.
I then right click on the message and want to select a public operation defined by the target class.

I am unable to right-click on message and find any UI to select any operation from the target class for the message.
When I try to right-click on message and select properties nothing shows.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Basically you are wrong in using classes in an SD. You must use instances!

Answer (score 1):

Sequence diagrams use class **instances**, not classes.

If you Define a class `Class` with an operation, and then drop the class as a lifeline (instance) on your sequence diagram you should see a name like `:Class` indicating this is an unnamed instance of the class `Class`

If you then select the message you have a dropdown in the properties window where you can select the operations available on `:Class` (no right clicks required)
[image]